# Showing the polynomial has integer coefficients

Tags: polynomials, irreducible-polynomials, cyclotomic-polynomials

Show that $\Phi_n(X)$ has integer coefficients.

The proofs [here](https://angyansheng.github.io/blog/an-elementary-proof-of-zsigmondys-theorem) states that $$\Phi_n(X)=\frac{X^n-1}{\prod_{d|n,d\ne n}\Phi_d(X)}.$$

And by long division, they get $\Phi_n(X)\in \Bbb{Q}[X]$. However, I am unable to understand how  $\Phi_n(X)\in \Bbb{Q}[X]$. After that, I can follow. The proof follows by using Gauss's lemma and since  $\Phi_n(X)\in \Bbb{Q}[X]$ and $ \prod_{d|n,d\ne n}\Phi_d(X),~~X^n-1\in \Bbb{Z}[X]\implies \Phi_n(X)\in\Bbb{Z}[X]$.

In general:

> If we have $g(x)=\frac{p(x)}{h(x)}$ where $p(x)\in\Bbb{Z}[X], h(x)\in\Bbb{Z}[X]$, prove that $g(x)\in\Bbb{Z}[X]$.

For this, if we can show that $g(x)\in \Bbb{Q}[X]$, then the proof is just same as above.

Comment: Have you used the fact that you have unitary polynomials?

Comment: The denominator is monic